# Django dataabse problem: (fields.E300) and (fields.E307)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Could you help me to fix this problem?
I know i can't import abstract class into database, but i have no idea how to fix my code :)

https://github.com/ichecinski/chess_guide

i have an error:

chess.Ruch.figura: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'Figura', which is either not installed, or is abstract.
chess.Ruch.figura: (fields.E307) The field chess.Ruch.figura was declared with a lazy reference to 'chess.figura', but app 'chess' doesn't provide model 'figura'.
`your text`

I tried to delte abstract class or change the ForeignKey, but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

In the class **Ruch**, the field **figura** is trying to stablish a relationship with a model (Figura) that doesn't exist in DB.

The class Figura is declared as abstract which serves as "template" for other models and this means that by itself it doesn't create any table in database. [More info about abstract classes here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes)

So the solution could be remove the field figura from class Ruch or declare Figura as not abstract (by doing this, you must refactor your other classes since they are extending from Figura).